# Problems with unicode symbols and xelatex on Windows 10 in English

Tags: xetex, symbols, unicode

I started to use `xelatex` on a Brazilian Portuguese installation of Windows 10, then I installed Ubuntu on English, and then I installed Windows 10 again, but in English.

`xelatex` supports UTF-8, so I was not using `inputenc` and all my accents and special caracters that I use in Portuguese was being printed to compile my documents, until I installed Windows 10 in English. Now only accents (à, á, â, ã...) are being printed, but not things like degree and numeral indicators (ª and º), instead it's printed symbols or letters that I don't even know what they are.

Here's an exemple with the exact same preamble I use in my documents:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath, amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fourier} 
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
Tentando escrever 2º lugar, mas falhando. Ela foi a 1ª colocada.

Acentuação tá em dia, só alguns símbolos que não.

90° também não funciona.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Did you also install a new TeX installation when you upgraded Windows? It looks like a recent update broke `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc` on Unicode engines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you build your document, the terminal contains this warning:

```
Package fourier Warning: Please consider loading "fourier-otf.sty" instead of
(fourier)                "fourier.sty" with Unicode engines LuaTeX or XeTeX,
(fourier)                so that Type1 fonts get replaced by OpenType fonts.
(fourier)                See file "Erewhon-Math.pdf" for more information.
```

so you should do just that.  The `fourier` package is for the pdfTeX engine, which doesn't support OTF fonts.

If I replace `\usepackage{fourier}` by `\usepackage{fourier-otf}` (and remove `amssymb` as advised by the package) the output is:

> [image]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsfonts, amsmath}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{fourier-otf}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}

\begin{document}
Tentando escrever 2º lugar, e está funcionando. Ela foi a 1ª colocada.

Acentuação tá em dia, só alguns símbolos que não.

90° funciona perfeitamente :)
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of June 2021, you get the bug whenever you load `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}` on either XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. I haven’t tracked it down in the kernel, and I’d echo Phelype Olenik’s advice to use Unicode fonts with XeLaTeX.  You would usually load 8-bit fonts in PDFTeX, which works fine with your MWE.  Another workaround for the mojibake you’re getting is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2cm, right=2.5cm, left=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage[brazilian]{babel}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\newunicodechar{°}{\textdegree}
\newunicodechar{ª}{\textordfeminine}
\newunicodechar{º}{\textordmasculine}

\begin{document}
Tentando escrever 2º lugar, mas falhando. Ela foi a 1ª colocada.

Acentuação tá em dia, só alguns símbolos que não.

90° também não funciona.
\end{document}
```

You no longer need to load `textcomp` with a recent LaTeX kernel, but it’s harmless.  You also don’t need `amssymb` or `amsfonts` with `fourier`, but this was unrelated to your problem.